# Browsers use monospace font for the ui (tabs, settings etc.)

Tags: arch-linux, firefox, fonts, browser, fontconfig

After updating my system (Arch linux x64) and installing some font packages, (I'm unsure what exactly caused this issue) all of my browsers (chromium, firefox, librewolf) started using the default system monospace font (FreeMono) for all the ui elements. (not the websites, the browser ui elements like the settings, tabs menu etc.)

I'm unsure what's causing this issue since it appears on different browsers and I don't see how my fontconfig could be affecting it.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Reinstalling all browsers (with cleared pacman cache)
- Uninstalling all the extra downloaded font packages
- Fiddling with the fonts.conf file
- Changing the firefox font settings
- Resetting all the entries containg `font` in about:config (firefox)

Here's my current fontconfig (~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "urn:fontconfig:fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    
  <match target="pattern">
    <test name="family" qual="any">
      <string>serif</string>
    </test>
    <edit binding="strong" mode="prepend" name="family">
      <string>FreeSerif</string>
    </edit>
  </match>

  <match target="pattern">
    <test name="family" qual="any">
      <string>monospace</string>
    </test>
    <edit binding="strong" mode="prepend" name="family">
      <string>FreeMono</string>
    </edit>
  </match>
  
  <match target="pattern">
    <test name="family" qual="any">
      <string>sans-serif</string>
    </test>
    <edit binding="strong" mode="prepend" name="family">
      <string>FreeSans</string>
    </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

And just to make sure that it's actually working here are the results of fc-match

```bash
$ fc-match sans-serif
FreeSans.otf: "FreeSans" "Regular"
$ fc-match serif
FreeSerif.otf: "FreeSerif" "Regular"
$ fc-match monospace
FreeMono.otf: "FreeMono" "Regular"
```